# From AsyncTask onPostExecute mehod is not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This asyncTask class is called in onCreate() method of Launcher Activity, I want to call service from this 2 AsyncTask class and storing data in sqlite database. but in these 2 asyncTask onPreExecute() and doInBackground() method is called but onPostExecute() method was never called. Please tell me why this happen, Thank you

```
public class EcafeHome extends Activity 
{
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            new GetOfferData(EcafeHome.this).execute("runnable");
            new GetMenuData(EcafeHome.this).execute("params");
        }
}

    public class GetOfferData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        Context mContext = null;
        public GetOfferData(Context mContext)
        {
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("GetOfferJsonData", "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            Log.d("GetOfferJsonData", "doInBackground");
            return Common.InputStreamToString(Common.HTTP_GET(Constant.host, Constant.serviceUrlProt, Constant.URL.catagoryList));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled(String result) 
        {
            super.onCancelled(result);
            Log.d("GetOfferJsonData", "onCancelled");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            Log.d("GetOfferJsonData", "onPostExecute");
            if(response != null)
            {
                Log.d("response", response);
                try 
                {
                    JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jArrayPackages = mJsonObject.getJSONArray(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE.PACKAGES); 

                    for(int i = 0; i < jArrayPackages.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jObjectPackages = jArrayPackages.getJSONObject(i);

                        int packageId = jObjectPackages.getInt(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE.ID);

                        String pkgName = jObjectPackages.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE.NAME);

                        int pkgprice = jObjectPackages.getInt(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE.PRICE);

                        String pkgpic = jObjectPackages.getString(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE.PIC);

                        DBConstant.openDatabase(mContext);
                        Cursor cursorOffer = DBConstant.mDBHelper.getPackageInfo(DBConstant.mSQLiteDatabase, packageId); 
                        if(cursorOffer != null)
                        {
                            Log.d("package offer", ""+cursorOffer.getCount());
                            if(cursorOffer.getCount() == 0)
                            {
                                DBConstant.mDBHelper.insertPackageInfo(DBConstant.mSQLiteDatabase, packageId, pkgName, pkgprice, pkgpic);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                        if(!cursorOffer.isClosed())
                            cursorOffer.close();

                        JSONArray jArrayPackageItem = jObjectPackages.getJSONArray(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE.PACKAGE_ITEMS);

                        for(int j = 0; j < jArrayPackageItem.length(); j++) 
                        {
                            JSONObject jObjectPackageItem = jArrayPackageItem.getJSONObject(j);
                            int pkgItemID = jObjectPackageItem.getInt(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE_ITEM.ID);

                            int pkgItemQnty = jObjectPackageItem.getInt(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE_ITEM.QUANTITY);

                            int menuitemid = jObjectPackageItem.getInt(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE_ITEM.MENU_ITEM_ID);

                            int pkgID = jObjectPackageItem.getInt(Constant.JSON_KEY.PACKAGE_ITEM.PACKAGE_ID);

                            //DBConstant.mDBHelper.insertPackageItemInfo(DBConstant.mSQLiteDatabase, pkgItemID, pkgID, menuitemid, pkgItemQnty);
                            DBConstant.openDatabase(mContext);
                            Cursor cursorOfferItem = DBConstant.mDBHelper.getPackageItemInfo(DBConstant.mSQLiteDatabase, pkgItemID); 
                            if(cursorOfferItem != null)
                            {
                                Log.d("package Item offer", ""+cursorOfferItem.getCount());
                                if(cursorOfferItem.getCount() == 0)
                                {
                                    DBConstant.mDBHelper.insertPackageItemInfo(DBConstant.mSQLiteDatabase, pkgItemID, pkgID, menuitemid, pkgItemQnty);
                                }
                            }
                            if(!cursorOfferItem.isClosed())
                                cursorOfferItem.close();

                            DBConstant.closeDatabase(); 
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this there are 2 AsyncTask that are not work parallel, I want to perform first both AsyncTask after than performing other task. so how it is implemented

Comment: multiple asynctask was not work in some os version so may be your one of task have problem with this please check one by one task from oncreate()

Answer (score 1):

Put the `super.onPostExecute(response);` at the bottom of `protected void onPostExecute(String response)`, after the line of codes.

Also `super.onPreExecute();` and `super.onCancelled(result);` on their method.

Comment: I think, i got this problem, In this there are 2 AsyncTask that are not work parallel, I want to perform first both AsyncTask after than performing other task. so how it is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you http request dont return result? Try in `doInBackground` return manyally result without internet interaction.

About two AsyncTask:

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

From here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I think, i got this problem, In this there are 2 AsyncTask that are not work parallel, I want to perform first both AsyncTask after than performing other task. so how it is implemented